# TF map_fn or while_loop for a list of tensors of different shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, control-flow

I want to process a sequence (a list) of tensors of different shape and output another list of tensors. Think RNN with different hidden state size on each timestamp. Something like

inputs: [tf.ones((1, 2, 2)), tf.ones((2, 2, 3)), tf.ones((3, 2, 1))]

outputs: [tf.zeros((1, 2, 4)), tf.zeros((4, 2, 6)), tf.zeros((6, 2, 1))]

I cannot stack inputs (or outputs) into a single tensor because they all have different shapes and thus I cannot use tf.map_fn for the task. For now, I use python for loops, but it seems to be suboptimal.

Is there something better I can do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`tf.while_loop`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop) to execute an arbitrary TensorFlow operation repeatedly, until some stopping condition occurs. The stopping condition is itself specified as an op.

Note that `tf.while_loop` should be used with care, as its iterations will run in parallel by default. For example, if the loop body increments a tf.Variable, then you must use [control dependencies](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/control_dependencies) to ensure that the iterations run in sequence.

**However,** you mentioned that you have a working implementation with a Python loop. When possible, using Python for the loop is usually the most efficient solution. When you build the loop in Python, you create separate ops for each iteration in the loop. This lets TensorFlow decide at graph-building how to assign computing resources to each op. For example, memory requirements and parallelization possibilities are easier to predict if the number of iterations is known in advance.

For this reason, `tf.while_loop` and `tf.map_fn` are most commonly used when the stopping condition is not known at graph-building time.

You might still want to use tf.while_loop instead of a Python loop if there is a fixed but very large number of iterations, because there is a nontrivial memory cost per op.

Comment: Thanks for explaining! I was under impression that using tf.while_loop is always faster because TF doesn't like large graphs.

Comment: I guess it depends on how big the graph is. I'd recommend (as with any optimization) to first implement whatever is simplest (which I guess you've already done), and optimize only if you really have a need to and only after verifying that this is indeed the performance bottleneck.