# python - get rid of python loop and replace with tensorflow calculation

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm doing tensorflow calculation and operations, and I have a python loop in the middle I'd like to get rid of. tensorflow split operation returns a list. tf.map could come in place but I cannot sort this out...

```
x = tf.random.uniform([10, 3])
x
Out[188]: 
<tf.Tensor: shape=(10, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0.6130438 , 0.9167876 , 0.65262306],
       [0.15292442, 0.2144351 , 0.394611  ],
       [0.0379566 , 0.05986917, 0.0370661 ],
       [0.56658876, 0.9666486 , 0.9957832 ],
       [0.50437593, 0.41686797, 0.68928134],
       [0.70317507, 0.70799184, 0.3758173 ],
       [0.14275837, 0.3472197 , 0.1068387 ],
       [0.01867867, 0.28552246, 0.34459472],
       [0.25262904, 0.5009186 , 0.780089  ],
       [0.740319  , 0.40693128, 0.38385737]], dtype=float32)>

split_indices = [2, 5, 3]
res = tf.split(x, split_indices)
mean_res = tf.convert_to_tensor([tf.reduce_mean(grp, axis=0) for grp in res])

mean_res
Out[192]: 
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0.3829841 , 0.56561136, 0.523617  ],
       [0.39097095, 0.49971947, 0.44095737],
       [0.3372089 , 0.3977908 , 0.502847  ]], dtype=float32)>
```

This is the code with the python loop.

When trying:

```
mean_res = tf.map_fn(fn=lambda t: tf.reduce_mean(t, axis=0), elems=res)

#ValueError: Dimensions 2 and 5 are not compatible
```

as we can see, the splits are 2, 5 and 3

Comment: wouldn't something like `mean_res = tf.map_fn(fn=lambda t: tf.reduce_mean(t, axis=0), res)` work?

Comment: Yeah I thought something like that would work but it doesn't :> Interpreter cries over different dimensions

Comment: Can you edit your question and show your attempt and the dimension error you get? I'm thinking it might have to do with the [map_fn](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn) unstacking the given elems?

Comment: Sure. Does it work on your machine?

Comment: I don't have a proper environment to test this right now, sorry... But maybe you can try to add `keepdims=True` to `tf.reduce_mean`? I think that reduce_mean is removing that dimension, and `map_fn` doesn't know how to collate the outputs afterwards

Comment: raise the same exception

Comment: Alright, it seems that `map_fn` is not designed to handle such a case, but according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49717913/20121320), you can perhaps use `tf.while_loop` instead